# Django Docker Postgresql database import export

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I have a problem with postgresql database. I just want to able to **export** and **import** database like **.sql** file. But when using command line I am able to get .sql database file but when I'm trying to import it to database it's giving **syntax errors** in sql file. I can try to fix syntax errors in sql file but I don't want to solve this problem it like that.
I need to get exported sql file without any errors and to be able to import it without any issue. What can be a problem?

Postgresql version:postgres:14.6

For example here is auto generated sql code by exporting db as sql file.
it gives syntax error in this line :
 `"id" bigint DEFAULT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "core_contact";
CREATE TABLE "public"."core_contact" (
    "id" bigint DEFAULT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    "first_name" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    "last_name" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    "company_name" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    "email" character varying(128) NOT NULL,
    "message" text NOT NULL,
    "created_at" timestamptz NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "core_contact_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) WITH (oids = false);
```

But, when I change it manually like that :    `"id" bigint NOT NULL,`
And it's working as expected.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "core_contact";
CREATE TABLE "public"."core_contact" (
    "id" bigint NOT NULL,
    "first_name" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    "last_name" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    "company_name" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    "email" character varying(128) NOT NULL,
    "message" text NOT NULL,
    "created_at" timestamptz NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "core_contact_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) WITH (oids = false);
```

What is the problem with postgres? Why it's not doing it correctly?